# How i setup paypal payment button?

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-buttons

I have a button that redirects to a paypal payment on my website. i want to do that only if you bought the thing im selling it will redirect to the download page and you can't access it just by typing the url of the download page, how i can do it? i couln't find anything about it on google

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need some type of access control system for your website or the content you distribute, which PayPal itself doesn't provide (it only processes the payment)

If you are not a programmer who can program an access control system on your own site, then you can either hire a developer to do it or find a third party solution that has this functionality. Going to the [PayPal Partner Directory](https://www.paypal.com/us/business/platforms-and-marketplaces/directory) and searching for the keyword "download" may be a good place to start, and a general web search for what features meet your needs is another place to look.

Comment: i think i can do that but how i can see if the payment from paypal was successful or not?

Comment: That will depend on how you integrate with PayPal. For your server to have an immediate and robust notification of a payment success, you should create and capture an order from your server, and use a JS button for the checkout approval flow.  See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ , and make sure you read through the optional step 5 in "Add and modify the code"